# Parse - PFObject not updating

Tags: iphone, ios, database, parse-platform

I am trying to create an app where each `PFObject` has categories `Verifications` and `Verified_By`.

`Verifications` consists of a number, and `Verified_By` is an array of strings

When I try to update the categories and save the `PFObject`, the data is correct and is saved locally, but when I call `saveInBackground`, it doesn't update in the data browser.

Here is my code for the updating:

```
 if (![verifiedBy containsObject:[ViewController getUserName]]) {
    //havent verified
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:verifiedBy];
    [newArray addObject:[ViewController getUserName]];
    [toModify setObject:newArray forKey:@"Verified_By"];
    [toModify incrementKey:@"Verifications"];
    [toModify saveInBackground];


    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Verified!" message:@"You have successfully verified this" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}
else {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Already Verified" message:@"You have already verified this" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
```

Comment: Have you tried `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` and checked for an error?

Comment: @Wain I did, and I received the output: `Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 101.)"` as well as `object not found for update`. I stepped through this, and all of the data is correct on the local device.

Comment: What relationships / roles does the object have?

Comment: @Wain not sure I understand your question. The object is responsible for holding data presented on screen, and if the user clicks a button, `Verifications` is incremented and `Verified_By` adds a string to it.

Comment: The error means something along the lines of "you're trying to save something which refers to something that isn't saved yet..."

Comment: @Wain do you know how I would be able to solve this?

Comment: Check through all the connections, what isn't saved to the server before you save this object (it could also be a role...)

Comment: Your `toModify` object, is it populated using one of the get/find operations, or are you making it yourself? It could be the issue if you're not creating/retrieving that object in the way you need to. Perhaps add the code that creates that object to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't have the proper `ParseACL` needs (public read = true, public write = true)